# Как кастомизировать грид в карусели slick slider?

Tags: css, jquery, slider, slick.js, slider-slick.js

Как создать [такой грид](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UbkSu.jpg) используя библиотеку slick.?
Пробовал манипуляции с flexbox, но выходит очень коряво =)

```js
$('.posts-curousel').slick({
  rows: 2,
  dots: true,
  arrows: false,
  infinite: true,
  speed: 300,
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 3
});
```

```css
.posts-curousel .slick-list {
  margin-left: -30px;
}

.posts-curousel .slick-slide {
    margin-left: 30px;
} 

.posts-curousel .posts-carusel-item {
    position: relative;
}

.posts-curousel .slick-dots {
    bottom: -20px;
    left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/slick/slick.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/slick/slick.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/slick/slick-theme.css" />
<div class="posts-curousel">
  <div class="posts-carusel-item">
    <div class="post-thumbnail">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://clevelonly.maxdroplet4.maxburst.dev/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/blog-image.webp" class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="">
    </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="posts-carusel-item">
    <div class="post-thumbnail">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://clevelonly.maxdroplet4.maxburst.dev/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/blog-image.webp" class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="">
    </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="posts-carusel-item">
    <div class="post-thumbnail">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://clevelonly.maxdroplet4.maxburst.dev/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/blog-image.webp" class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="">
    </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="posts-carusel-item">
    <div class="post-thumbnail">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://clevelonly.maxdroplet4.maxburst.dev/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/blog-image.webp" class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="">
    </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="posts-carusel-item">
    <div class="post-thumbnail">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://clevelonly.maxdroplet4.maxburst.dev/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/blog-image.webp" class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="">
    </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="posts-carusel-item">
    <div class="post-thumbnail">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://clevelonly.maxdroplet4.maxburst.dev/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/blog-image.webp" class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="">
    </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="posts-carusel-item">
    <div class="post-thumbnail">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://clevelonly.maxdroplet4.maxburst.dev/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/blog-image.webp" class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="">
    </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="posts-carusel-item">
    <div class="post-thumbnail">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://clevelonly.maxdroplet4.maxburst.dev/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/blog-image.webp" class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="">
    </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="posts-carusel-item">
    <div class="post-thumbnail">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://clevelonly.maxdroplet4.maxburst.dev/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/blog-image.webp" class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="">
    </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Не нашел там ничего подобного

Comment: если вам грид надо сделать внутри слайда, то при чем тут сам слик?

Comment: У слик есть свои стили и условия для отображения карусели. Я попробовал сделать подобный грид используя флекс и отображение карусели в 2 колонки, но что-то видмо делаю не так.

Comment: добавьте в вопрос сниппет с вашим кодом, чтобы о конкретике говорить, а не абстракциях

Comment: Вот такого вида он сейчас.